# Missing keys when loading the model weight in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I plan to load weight from a pth file, e.g.,

```
model = my_model()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("../input/checkpoint/checkpoint.pth")
```

However, here is an error, saying:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for my_model:
Missing key(s) in state_dict: "att.in_proj_weight", "att.in_proj_bias", "att.out_proj.weight", "att.out_proj.bias". 
Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "in_proj_weight", "in_proj_bias", "out_proj.weight", "out_proj.bias".
```

seems that the parameter name of my model is different from the one that stored in the `state_dict`. In this case, how am I supposed to make them consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new dictionary and modify keys without `att.` prefix and you can load the new dictionary to your model as following:

```py
state_dict = torch.load('path\to\checkpoint.pth')

from collections import OrderedDict
new_state_dict = OrderedDict()

for key, value in state_dict.items():
    key = key[4:] # remove `att.`
    new_state_dict[key] = value

# load params
model = my_model()
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to overwrite the model with the new one, you can use that script:

```
import torch
from collections import OrderedDict

source = "../input/checkpoint/checkpoint.pth"

state_dict = torch.load(source)
new_state_dict = OrderedDict()

for key, value in state_dict.items():
    new_key = ".".join(key.split(".")[1:])
    new_state_dict[new_key] = value

torch.save(new_state_dict, source)
```